# I get invalid even when I have input the valid detail

Tags: c#, email

When a valid detail is input it still shows invalid  code for the content in the design when the first name is bigger   then 15 then i want error and I also dont want the first name or the surname to be repeated.So when I enter the right detail my program still shows error I want it to show submitted when the right details are inserted.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public DateTime? currentDate;
    public string previousDate;
    public string previousFirstName = "";
    public string previousSurname = "";
    public string previousEmailAddress = "";
    int previousTimeIndex = 12;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var datePicker = sender as DatePicker;

        currentDate = datePicker.SelectedDate;
    }

    private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // validation checks
        string Title = comboBox.Text;
        string FirstName = First_Name.Text;
        string Surname = Sur_name.Text;
        string EmailAddress = Email_Address.Text;
        int TimeSelector = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;
        // valid or not switch
        bool validInput = true;

        // Title can only be one of these in my design its a drop down box so
        // when the title is not one of them I want to see a error saying invalid
        if (Title != "Mr" && Title != "Mrs" && Title != "Miss" && Title != "Other")
        {
            validInput = false;
        }

        if (FirstName.Length > 15) // first name
        {
            validInput = false;
        }

        if (Surname.Length > 15) // surname
        {
            validInput = false;
        }

        if (!EmailAddress.Contains("@") || !EmailAddress.Contains(".co") || !EmailAddress.Contains(".co.uk") ||
            !EmailAddress.Contains(".com")) // email address
        {
            validInput = false;
        }

        if (currentDate.ToString().Equals(previousDate)) // current date
        {
            validInput = false;
        }

        // Time selector
        if (TimeSelector == previousTimeIndex)
        {
            validInput = false;
        }

        // Submit button code
        if (validInput == true)
        {
            submit.Content = "Submitted";
            // I also dont wanna be able to enter the same name again
            //if the same name is to be used twice it has to in a different time.
            previousDate = currentDate.ToString();
            previousFirstName = FirstName;
            previousSurname = Surname;
            previousEmailAddress = EmailAddress;
        }
        else
        {
            submit.Content = "Invalid Input(s)";
        }
    }
}   .............................................................................
```

Comment: What do you consider as a valid input, could you give an example for each field?

Comment: So for title I would like Mr/mrs/miss/other

Comment: for name I would like for the name to only be inserted once same with the surname

Comment: for the email I would like it to only take the input if there is a .com .co.uk and @

Comment: for date I would like it to only take dates ahead so if the date is privious then I would like it to give invalid input

Comment: This should be fairly easy to debug - did you try? Also if this a WPF application you should add the MainWindow.xaml.

Comment: You're saying that even when you have the valid details you get an invalid result, I am asking if you could tell us what you entered as _valid inputs_. What values did you give `FirstName`, `Title` and all the others.

Comment: I dont have a fixed valid input

Comment: It doesn't have to be fixed. The problem is that you are not being specific about what is failing. You should give an example (in your question above) of some input that you entered which you consider to be valid that the program says is invalid.

Comment: Try setting a break point and stepping through the code to see where it's failing. We cannot guess what input you are putting in, or where it's failing based on the information you're giving.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the line that validates the EmailAddress:

```
if (!EmailAddress.Contains("@") || !EmailAddress.Contains(".co") || !EmailAddress.Contains(".co.uk") || !EmailAddress.Contains(".com")) // email address
```

For this check to return a valid result, your EmailAddress has to contain `@` and one of `.co`, `.co.uk` and `.com`. You probably want something like this

```
if (!EmailAddress.Contains("@") || (!EmailAddress.Contains(".co") && !EmailAddress.Contains(".co.uk") && !EmailAddress.Contains(".com"))) // email address
```

Comment: It works now but only one time so when I put the details and press submit it submits but then after that it gives invalid inut again

Comment: Try setting a break point and stepping through the code to see where it's failing. We cannot guess what input you are putting in, or where it's failing based on the information you're giving.